# Ghost zombie conflict in Darcs

Tags: conflict, darcs

I have a "ghost zombie conflict" in my repositories.

Once upon a time there was a conflict whereupon me and my colleague modified the same lines in a certain file. No biggie, stuff like this happens. I resolved the conflict like I always do (I believe this to be the correct way, please correct me if I'm mistaken) by editing the result file so that the content makes sense and the conflict markers are gone, then `darcs rec`.

I have a couple of branches in different places, in development, testing and staging for instance. Whenever I `apply` the changes (or `pull` for that matter) the conflict is reintroduced (hence zombie). Darcs warns about a conflict, throws a bunch of markers in the file and I have to manually go and resolve the conflict again. The problem is that after I've removed the unnecessary parts, `darcs wh` shows no changes in the file (hence ghost)!

I'm completely at a loss as to 1) what happened 2) how can I fix it and 3) how can I prevent it in the future.

Comment: What version of darcs are you using and what format is the repository (the contents of '_darcs/format' will tell you the latter)? If you can share your repository it'll be easier to diagnose what's happened. Generally speaking editing the result file and 'darcs rec' is indeed the right thing to do.